# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'threshold'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter

[code of the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84fX2.png)
I am learing ML through the book [Building MachineLearningSystemWithPython 2nd edition by Willi Richert and Luis Pedro Coelho](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch02/chapter.py), and here in Chapter 2 it has used "fit_model" , and while looking for the code in GitHub of this book it has imported fit_model from threshold library as 
"from threshold import fit_model" but it gives error while doing so. Sorry if this was a naive question.
[error_while_trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84fX2.png)

I am trying this code in jupyter via anaconda-navigator and i have no idea what's worng.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in the repo under **threshold.py** file. You need to git clone the repo to your local computer and then run the file you want.